# Best way to use TFS on new Project

Tags: tfs, revision

About to start a new project in VS2010 which will have a few windows services, a few dlls,  a GUI application and a MS SQL Database.

What is the best what to handle these in source control and more specify Team Foundation Server?

On previous projects we used Tortoise SVN to commit each component separately to the repository and there was no connection between projects from a revision control point of view. I am particularly interested in how the database should be managed having never done any development with databases before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[How To: Structure Your Source Control Folders in Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668992.aspx)

[patterns & practices Team Development with TFS Guide (Final Release)](http://tfsguide.codeplex.com/)

[Visual Studio TFS Branching Guide 2010](http://tfsbranchingguideiii.codeplex.com/)

Comment: +1 The folder structure outlined in the first link is THE SCM best practice layout (see http://www.amazon.co.uk/Software-Configuration-Management-Patterns-Integration/dp/0201741172/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1280826878&sr=8-1 "Software Configuration Management Patterns").

Comment: +1 I have blogged about this before with my own methods. But this best practices guidence superseeds it. I will update my blog.